# how to give hyperlink to images in "jquery image cycle"?

Tags: jquery

I've used **j query images cycle plugin** in the website I'm building. Is it possible to give hyperlinks to those images in cycle, If the answer is yes please tel me how to?

This the working code for images inside without any hyper-link

```
<div class="wrapper col2">
  <div id="featured_slide">
    <ul class="roundabout-holder">
      <li><img src="images/demo/ComputerScience.gif" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/demo/InformationScience.gif" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/demo/Mechanical.gif" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

for single instance this is I tried

```
     <li>
         <a href="http://www.stunspot.com">
    <img src="images/demo/computerscience.gif" alt="" />
     </a>
    </li>
```

above code did not not work means it still working as it was.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: do you want all images to have the same link, or each to have unique hyperlink? Also can you provide your sample code?

Comment: as you all asked what i edited my question, if that is still not enough i will post slider code to. but i believe that has nothing to with hyperlink. because that only describes how to present the images.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and the details you have provided, You can do something link below. Replace the # with the link you want.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    timeout: 3000, 
    pager:  '#nav', 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
    } 
});
```

Read more [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23)